# IO exception: Size Data Unit (SDU) mismatch. Vendor code 17002

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, jdbc-odbc

I am connecting through VPN to school site to access DB.
I use SQL developer 3.0.04 to connect this database. But if I try to connect it this exception is thrown: "IO exception: Size Data Unit (SDU) mismatch. Vendor code 17002"

Does anybody have experience with that kind of problem? I really cannot find solution.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've solved it by installing latest version of sql developer